# ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I wrote a data migration script in which I am checking if the previous data migration is in process then close all db connections this mean change the database mode which is `MULTI_USER` mode to `RESTRICTED_USER` mode 
by donig so my database will go on restricted mode and only autherised connection will be allowed after change the database mode I am updating my some column and after that I am restoring db to multi user mode

But when I run it gives me following error

> Msg 6401, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_CollegeMigration, Line 234
>   Cannot roll back CollegeMigration. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.
>
> Msg 226, Level 16, State 6, Procedure SP_CollegeMigration, Line 236
>   ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.
>
> Msg 50000, Level 16, State 6, Procedure SP_CollegeMigration, Line 260
>   ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction.

This is some of my script

```
IF(@preMigrationStatus = 'InProcess' and @isForceFull = 'Yes')
BEGIN
/*if the previous migration is in process then inside if i am changing the 
 db mode to restricted_user mode 
*/ 
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
ALTER DATABASE  AlAhsaan2014 SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

UPDATE TblCollegeMigrationHistory
SET MigrationStatus ='Failed',
    Comments = Comments + 'Migration Failed at '+ Convert(nvarchar, getdate()) + ' ;'
WHERE HistoryID = @HistoryId;

ALTER DATABASE AlAhsaan2014 SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
/* select statement goes here  */

END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style should **no longer be used** and instead it is recommended to use the **proper ANSI JOIN** syntax introduced with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: Separate your statement batches with `GO`

Comment: why my question down voted ?

Comment: @marc_s: i know this is bad style but my question was not about style or join my question was about ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction

Comment: @DavidG: by using `GO` my variables which is declared above not accessable and generating errors

Comment: It's not just *bad style* - because you're listing those three tables and selects **without** any join condition, you're creating a **cartesian product** - is that really what you want?? Just get used to using **proper ANSI join syntax**

Comment: in my case certesian product does not matter beacuse it will return only one row thats why i join like this any how i will use that you suggest ..have you know whats is going wrong with that script why multistatement error occured ?

Comment: Is this all of your code? I'm guessing no, because "Cannot roll back CollegeMigration` suggests there is a transaction going on. In that case, the error message is telling you *exactly* what is wrong: you can't use `ALTER DATABASE` in a multi-statement transaction. Twiddling `IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS` is not going to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem 
by creating a  new `storedprocedure` and place these two lines into the procedure

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
ALTER DATABASE  AlAhsaan2014 SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

and then call the storedprocedure from my script

```
IF(@preMigrationStatus = 'InProcess' and @isForceFull = 'Yes')
BEGIN
/*if the previous migration is in process then inside if i am changing the 
 db mode to restricted_user mode 
*/ 

exec sp_changeDbMode 

UPDATE TblCollegeMigrationHistory
SET MigrationStatus ='Failed',
    Comments = Comments + 'Migration Failed at '+ Convert(nvarchar, getdate()) + ' ;'
WHERE HistoryID = @HistoryId;

ALTER DATABASE AlAhsaan2014 SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
/* select statement goes here  */

END
```